# Converting a pandas series output to string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the output of a query in pandas from the format of a series to the format of a string.
The function is below (Gold* are columns)

```
def try_three():
    import numpy as np
    nz=df[(df["Gold"]>0) & (df["Gold.1"]>0) & (df["Gold.2"]>0)]
    nz["average"]=((nz["Gold"])-(nz["Gold.1"]))/(nz["Gold.2"])
    return nz.where(nz["average"]==np.max(nz["average"])).dropna()["ID"]
```

The output is

```
Country
Bulgaria    BUL
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

where Country is the name of the index and BUL is the value of the ID field.
I have already tried to append .astype(str) to get just the name of the country or the ID, but with no success. If I prepend "len" I get the answer 1, so I think there is something similar and just as simple to get the output as a string.

Comment: For not showing any sample data -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If output is always 1 element `Series` ( because only one `max`) use [`Series.item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html):

```
nz.where(nz["average"]==np.max(nz["average"])).dropna()["ID"].item()
```

But if possible multiple max values then if failed.

---

So is posible return list or joined `string` from list:

```
nz.where(nz["average"]==np.max(nz["average"])).dropna()["ID"].tolist()
```

Or:

```
', '.join(nz.where(nz["average"]==np.max(nz["average"])).dropna())["ID"].tolist()
```

If want general solution:

```
a = nz.where(nz["average"]==np.max(nz["average"])).dropna()["ID"]

if len(a) == 1:
    return a.item()
else:
    return ', '.join(a) # a.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want to get the first element in Series (`ID` column):

```
df['ID'].iat[0]
```

Demo:

```
In [77]: df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['BUL']}, index=['Bulgaria']).rename_axis('Country')

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
           ID
Country
Bulgaria  BUL

In [79]: df['ID']
Out[79]:
Country
Bulgaria    BUL
Name: ID, dtype: object

In [80]: df['ID'].iat[0]
Out[80]: 'BUL'
```

Comment: This was not exactly was I was seeking, since I wanted something more general. Nevertheless, your answer was also helpful. Thanks also for indenting my code.